# JavaScript Object Collision With Squares

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am trying to make the blue object collide with the green one, but I cannot get the whole area of the square, i only detect half....and down the entire Y + X axis's

```
  if (blue.x >= green.x && blue.y >= green.y){
    console.log('BOOM');
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to post a complete code example. That little snippet isn't going to cut it.

Comment: If you google "collision detection rectangles" you'll find many tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by commenters above, you'll need to read up on rectangle collision detection. Checking `if (rect1.x == rect2.x && rect1.y == rect2.y)` will only ever be true if both rectangles are originating from the exact same set of points (i.e. they are overlapping from the same x and y origins).